# Concatenate and shuffle entries in a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, numpy, string-concatenation

Suppose I have a list (or a NumPy array) of strings, e.g., X = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'], a list of indices, e.g., J = [0, 3], and a random permutation p, e.g., [0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4].

I want to find the most time efficient way to concatenate the strings in X corresponding to the indices J, i.e., concatenate X[j] for each j in J to get 'abcjkl', and apply the permutation p to this string, i.e., 'ajclbk'. Applying a permutation p to a string Y results in another string Z such that Z[i] = Y[p[i]].

**Right now, I have X, J, and p as NumPy arrays and do**

```
X = numpy.array(['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'])
J = numpy.array([0, 3])
p = numpy.array([0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4])
Y = ''.join(X[J])
Z = numpy.array(list(Y))
res = ''.join(Z[p])
```

Is there a faster way to achieve this? *I don't have to use NumPy arrays if a solution with lists exist*. In my application, list X can have 10 Million strings (formed using the English alphabet) each of length 1000, indices J can be of length 5 Million, and permutation p can be of length 5 Billion.

Comment: what do u mean by apply a permutation to a string.. do u mean return an array of the different orderings of the letters in the string ? So if permutation is 3, and string is `abcd`, then 3 different ways of ordering abcd ?

Comment: Also what have u tried so far ? Maybe if u add that we can get a better idea of what is it u r trying to acheive here.

Comment: @leoOrion By applying a permutation p to a string X I mean I want a new string Y whose ith element Y[i] = X[p[i]]. I've included examples in the question along with what I've tried so far

Comment: Your example is not even valid python ? U cant do X[J] where J is another list.

Comment: @leoOrion You can do that if X and J are numpy arrays

Comment: Please edit ur question and ur code to explicitly say only numpy arrays. U ahve emntioend lists or numpy. Lists dont allow this.

Comment: I have listed that I use NumPy arrays just before the code block, but I do not necessarily have to use NumPy arrays if a solution with lists exists

Comment: Are the "strings" all the same length? Can they use any Unicode, or will they be restricted to ASCII or some similar restriction?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, the strings are of the same length (on the order of 1000). You can assume that they are restricted to the English Alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Under the assumption that the strings in the original input are of equal length, you can resolve indices concatenation, which, combined with [`np.ndarray.view()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html), would allow for a very fast NumPy-only implementation:

```py
import numpy as np


def take2s_reidx_np(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    k = len(arr[0])
    q, r = np.divmod(idx_b, k)
    return arr.view(("U", 1))[r + k * idx_a[q]].view(("U", len(idx_b)))[0]
```

which can be re-implemented with Numba to minimize temporary memory usage:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def apply_cat_idx_nb(arr, idx_a, idx_b, k):
    n = len(idx_b)
    result = np.empty(n, dtype=arr.dtype)
    for i in range(n):
        q, r = divmod(idx_b[i], k)
        result[i] = arr[r + k * idx_a[q]]
    return result


def take2s_at_reidx_nb(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    # use `np.int32` as a proxy of `("U", 1)` because of Numba support
    return apply_cat_idx_nb(arr.view(np.int32), idx_a, idx_b, len(arr[0])).view(("U", len(idx_b)))[0]
```

It is unclear if using `np.uint8` internally leads to any speed advantage for the more optimized methods.

While if the input uses `bytes` instead of `str`, this operation is typically (much?) faster TODO

---

## Longer Answer

Actually, NumPy arrays should be the most convenient containers to solve this problem when it comes to speed, especially for very large inputs.

However, there is no need to go back and forth to strings (or bytes): you can just apply the indices on the array themselves, or a suitable view of it with [`np.ndarray.view()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html), which is a brutally cheap operation. The same operation is also used to view the data again in `str` format.

Assuming OP's code can be summarized by the following function:

```py
import numpy as np


def take2s_OP(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    tmp_str = "".join(arr[idx_a])
    tmp_arr = np.array(list(tmp_str))
    return "".join(tmp_arr[idx_b])
```

a solution based on `np.ndarray.view()` would look like:

```py
def take2s_np(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    return arr[idx_a].view(("U", 1))[idx_b].view(("U", len(idx_b)))[0]
```

The above does have the advantage of working with Unicode strings (not just ASCII) and does not require prior input manipulation.

Now, there is still a relatively expensive (`O(n)`) computation: the [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), which is done twice in the above code.

By using the fact that the strings are of the same length `k`, we can write a single index `idx_ab` as the combination of the two `idx_a` followed by `idx_b`:

```
r, q = divmod(idx_b, k)
idx_ab = r + k * idx_a[q]
arr[idx_ab] == arr[idx_a][idx_b]
```

With NumPy this would look something like:

```py
def take2s_reidx_np(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    k = len(arr[0])
    q, r = np.divmod(idx_b, k)
    return arr.view(("U", 1))[r + k * idx_a[q]].view(("U", len(idx_b)))[0]
```

However, the above still creates a large temporary array to store the indices that are used only once.
It would be more efficient to generate and access the indices on the go, thus removing the need for the large temporary object.
For this, it is possible to write some explicit loops to be accelerated with Numba:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def apply_cat_idx_nb(arr, idx_a, idx_b, k):
    n = len(idx_b)
    result = np.empty(n, dtype=arr.dtype)
    for i in range(n):
        q, r = divmod(idx_b[i], k)
        result[i] = arr[r + k * idx_a[q]]
    return result


def take2s_at_reidx_nb(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    # use `np.int32` as a proxy of `("U", 1)` because of Numba support
    return apply_cat_idx_nb(arr.view(np.int32), idx_a, idx_b, len(arr[0])).view(("U", len(idx_b)))[0]
```

Note that the original array is initially viewed as `np.int32` (which matches the Unicode datatype size) because the creation of Unicode arrays is still unsupported with Numba.

Since [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) is a heavily optimized functionality in NumPy, it may be more efficient to still use that and a temporary array to store the indices, but to create them with Numba accelerated code:

```py
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def cat_idx_nb(idx_a, idx_b, k):
    n = len(idx_b)
    result = np.empty(n, dtype=idx_b.dtype)
    for i in range(n):
        q, r = divmod(idx_b[i], k)
        result[i] = r + k * idx_a[q]
    return result


def take2s_reidx_nb(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    idx_ab = cat_idx_nb(idx_a, idx_b, len(arr[0]))
    return arr.view(("U", 1))[idx_ab].view(("U", len(idx_b)))[0]
```

---

Eventually, working with `bytes` instead of `str` is going to be faster (but limited to ASCII characters).

The get from the NumPy array of characters to the `bytes`, one can simply use the [`np.ndarray.tobytes()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) method.

The approaches presented earlier would read:

```py
def take2b_OP(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    tmp_bstr = b"".join(arr[idx_a])
    tmp_arr = np.array(list(tmp_bstr), dtype=np.uint8)
    return b"".join(tmp_arr[idx_b])


def take2b_np(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    return arr[idx_a].view(np.uint8)[idx_b].tobytes()


def take2b_reidx_np(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    k = len(arr[0])
    q, r = np.divmod(idx_b, k)
    return arr.view(np.uint8)[r + k * idx_a[q]].tobytes()


def take2b_reidx_nb(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    idx_ab = cat_idx_nb(idx_a, idx_b, len(arr[0]))
    return arr.view(np.uint8)[idx_ab].tobytes()


def take2b_at_reidx_nb(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    return apply_cat_idx_nb(arr.view(np.uint8), idx_a, idx_b, len(arr[0])).tobytes()
```

---

If your string do contain only ASCII characters you could also view the Unicode data of size `N` type in the input NumPy array as `np.uint8` instead of Unicode data of size 1. Care must be taken to ensure that `np.uint8` items (1 byte) are aligned to the Unicode items (4 bytes), so one needs to read every 4 chars, but that is a simple slicing:

```py
def take2sbs_np(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    return arr[idx_a].view(np.uint8)[::4][idx_b].tobytes().decode()
```

Under the assumption of ASCII-only strings, these can be re-written to use `np.uint8` internally, as long as one accounts for the padding mismatch in the Unicode datatype in NumPy compared to `np.uint8` (Unicode datatype uses 4 bytes per char) and uses a different approach to converting the data back to string (essentially combining [`np.ndarray.tobytes()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) with  [`str.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) method to get back to a `str`), e.g.:

```py
def take2s_reidx_u8_np(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    k = len(arr[0])
    q, r = np.divmod(idx_b, k)
    return arr.view(np.uint8)[::4][r + k * idx_a[q]].tobytes().decode()


def take2s_reidx_u8_nb(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    idx_ab = cat_idx_nb(idx_a, idx_b, len(arr[0]))
    return arr.view(np.uint8)[::4][idx_ab].tobytes().decode()
```

It is unclear if using `np.uint8` internally leads to any speed advantage for the more optimized methods.

---

For completeness I also include also two solutions (one for `str`, one for `bytes`) based on [@KarlKnechtel's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73455351/5218354):

```py
def take2s_2d(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    arr_2d = np.array([list(x.encode()) for x in arr], dtype=np.uint8)
    return bytes(arr_2d[idx_a, :].ravel()[idx_b]).decode()
```

```py
def take2b_2d(arr, idx_a, idx_b):
    arr_2d = np.array([list(x) for x in arr], dtype=np.uint8)
    return bytes(arr_2d[idx_a, :].ravel()[idx_b])
```

which have a similar spirit as `take2b_np()`, but do require some relatively heavy input manipulation.

---

To check that these approaches are all equivalent, here are reported being applied to OP's input:

```
s_funcs = take2s_OP, take2s_np, take2s_2d, take2s_reidx_np, take2s_reidx_nb, take2s_at_reidx_nb, take2s_reidx_u8_np, take2s_reidx_u8_nb
b_funcs = take2b_OP, take2b_np, take2b_2d, take2b_reidx_np, take2b_reidx_nb, take2b_at_reidx_nb

X = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"]
Xs = np.array(X)
Xb = np.array([x.encode() for x in X])
J = np.array([0, 3])
p = np.array([0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4])

for func in s_funcs:
    print(f"{func.__name__:>20s}  {func(Xs, J, p)}")

for func in b_funcs:
    print(f"{func.__name__:>20s}  {func(Xb, J, p)}")
```

---

And to see which one is faster for large inputs one can use:

```py
import string


M = 1000  # string length
n = 500_000
p = n // 2
q = n // 2

idx_a = np.random.randint(0, n, p)
idx_b = np.random.randint(0, M * p, q)
```

```py
arr_s = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), (o * M)).view(("U", M))
base = take2s_np2(arr_s, idx_a, idx_b)
print(f"`str` funcs, n={len(arr_s)}")
for func in s_funcs:
    res = func(arr_s, idx_a, idx_b)
    print(f"{func.__name__:>20s}  {base == res}  ", end="")
    %timeit func(arr_s, idx_a, idx_b)
# `str` funcs, n=500000
#            take2s_OP  True  38.1 s ± 989 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#            take2s_np  True  591 ms ± 40.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#            take2s_2d  True  31.7 s ± 1.49 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#      take2s_reidx_np  True  15.9 ms ± 702 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#      take2s_reidx_nb  True  12.4 ms ± 580 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#   take2s_at_reidx_nb  True  18.4 ms ± 3.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#   take2s_reidx_u8_np  True  14.5 ms ± 666 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#   take2s_reidx_u8_nb  True  11.8 ms ± 1.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
arr_b = np.array([x.encode() for x in arr_s])
base = take2b_np2(arr_b, idx_a, idx_b)
print(f"`bytes` funcs, n={len(arr_b)}")
for func in b_funcs:
    res = func(arr_b, idx_a, idx_b)
    print(f"{func.__name__:>20s}  {base == res}  ", end="")
    %timeit func(arr_b, idx_a, idx_b)
# `bytes` funcs, n=500000
#            take2b_OP  True  14.4 s ± 1.34 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#            take2b_np  True  150 ms ± 9.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
#            take2b_2d  True  30.7 s ± 1.22 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#      take2b_reidx_np  True  13 ms ± 722 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#      take2b_reidx_nb  True  9.13 ms ± 686 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#   take2b_at_reidx_nb  True  12.8 ms ± 1.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Note that I used `N = 500_000` as larger values would deplete system memory.

---

## More Benchmarks

To get some idea how the different methods fare for different input sizes, one can use the following functions, where `n` is the size of `arr`, `p` the size of `idx_a` and `q` the size of `idx_b`:

```py
import string
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def benchmark(
    funcs,
    ii=range(2, 15, 1),
    m=16,
    is_equal=lambda a, b: all(x == y for x, y in zip(a, b)),
    seed=0,
    unit="ms",
    verbose=True,
    use_str=True
):
    labels = [func.__name__ for func in funcs]
    units = {"s": 0, "ms": 3, "µs": 6, "ns": 9}
    assert unit in units
    np.random.seed(seed)

    M = 1000  # string length
    timings = {}
    for i in ii:
        n = 2 ** i
        p = n // 2
        q = n // 2
        if verbose:
            print(f"i={i}, n={n}, m={m}, k={k}  (p={p}, q={q})")
        alph = string.ascii_letters
        if use_str:
            arr = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), (n * M)).view(("U", M))
        else:
            arr = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters.encode()), (n * M)).astype(np.uint8).view(("S", M))
        idx_a = np.random.randint(0, n, p)
        idx_b = np.random.randint(0, M * p, q)
        base = funcs[0](arr, idx_a, idx_b)
        timings[n] = []
        for func in funcs:
            res = func(arr, idx_a, idx_b)
            is_good = is_equal(base, res)
            timed = %timeit -n 16 -r 4 -q -o [func(arr, idx_a, idx_b) for arr in arrs]
            timing = timed.best / k
            timings[n].append(timing if is_good else None)
            if verbose:
                print(
                    f"{func.__name__:>24}"
                    f"  {is_good!s:5}"
                    f"  {timing * (10 ** units[unit]):10.3f} {unit}"
                    f"  {timings[n][0] / timing:6.1f}x")
    return timings, labels


def plot(timings, labels, title=None, xlabel="Input Size / #", unit="ms"):
    n_rows = 1
    n_cols = 3
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols, figsize=(8 * n_cols, 6 * n_rows), squeeze=False)
    units = {"s": 0, "ms": 3, "µs": 6, "ns": 9}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=timings, index=labels).transpose()
    
    base = df[[labels[0]]].to_numpy()
    (df * 10 ** units[unit]).plot(marker="o", xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=f"Best timing / {unit}", ax=axs[0, 0])
    (df / base * 100).plot(marker='o', xlabel=xlabel, ylabel='Relative speed / %', logx=True, ax=axs[0, 1])
    (base / df).plot(marker='o', xlabel=xlabel, ylabel='Speed Gain / x', ax=axs[0, 2])

    if title:
        fig.suptitle(title)
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
```

called with:

```py
s_timings, s_labels = benchmark(s_funcs, unit="ms", use_str=True, verbose=True)
plot(s_timings, s_labels, "Benchmark with `str`", unit="ms")

b_timings, b_labels = benchmark(b_funcs, unit="ms", use_str=False, verbose=True)
plot(b_timings, b_labels, "Benchmark with `bytes`", unit="ms")
```

to get the following plots:

[image: bm_str]
[image: bm_bytes]

Indicating that:

- reindexing-based approaches lead to *much* faster execution (~4000x or more for even modest input size of ~2000 chars)
- `take2*_np()` approaches is much faster than the OP's but much slower than reindexing
- reindexing with advanced indexing done together seems to be generally on par compared to performing the two separately
- it is unclear whether using `np.uint8` for `str` input is beneficial.
- working with `bytes` seems to be generally faster
- `take2s_2d()` seems to be marginally faster than `take2s_OP()`
- `take2b_2d()` seems to be largely slower than `take2b_OP()`
- `take2b_2d()` and `take2s_2d()` seem to be largely on par

This means that the "preparation" of the input in `take2*_2d()` adds a significant penalty to the overall approach, which should otherwise be of similar performance as `take2b_np()`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Your take2s_np function works right off the bat without making any changes to the input np array X (of strings). I found it to be roughly 2x faster for my application compared to Karl's approach (including pre-processing times). Should I do some postprocessing to your take2b_np function to make it work for strings? Sorry if this is a naive question, I'm relatively new to Python

Comment: Glad it helped! To convert strings to bytes, if they are literals, just prepend b, otherwise call the encode method.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to pass in X_enc = np.array([list(v.encode()) for v in X], dtype=np.uint8) as input to take2b_np along with the arrays X, J, p in my example. I get the error "IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2" since p has entries all the way up to 5 but X_enc[J].view(np.uint8) is a two-dimensional np array of dimension (2,3). Am I missing something? Also, should I perform a decode step after using take2b_np? Will this function still outperform take2s_np even with the encoding and decoding times included?

Comment: I found that replacing arr[idx_a].view(np.uint8)[idx_b].tobytes() with arr[idx_a].view(np.uint8).reshape((len(idx_b,1))[idx_b].tobytes().decode() in tak2b_np does the trick. Is this the best approach?

Comment: @madnessweasley The `take2b_*()` methods require `bytes` input (array of `bytes`) and output `bytes`. You can use `str.decode()` on their output to get back to `str` inputs. My tests indicates that it is unclear whether using a `np.uint8` internal representation is beneficial. But see my update answer, for an even faster method using reindexing (indexing concatenation).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I found that solutions using numba/re_idx are at least 2x slower than your initial numpy solution with take2s_np. This probably depends on my laptop's architecture...

Comment: @madnessweasley Have you tried other approaches? With your numbers, I'd bet on `take2s_at_reidx_nb()` (perhaps make sure you have a reasonably recent LLVM version).

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, the strings are of the same length (on the order of 1000). You can assume that they are restricted to the English Alphabet

Under these conditions I would expect Numpy to offer considerable advantages. (I also assume here that `X` can be pre-processed and will be reused with varying `J` and `p` values.)

Represent `X` as a 2D array of bytes (really, 8-bit numeric values, not the Python `bytes` type):

```
X = np.array([list(b'abc'), list(b'def'), list(b'ghi'), list(b'jkl')], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Concatenate by slicing appropriately and then using `ravel`:

```
J = (0, 3)
Y = X[J,:].ravel()
```

Permute as before; then instead of using `join` to join up the bytes (there *is* an equivalent for the `bytes` type, but it's overkill), just pass the array directly to the `bytes` constructor:

```
p = (0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4)
Z = bytes(Y[p,]) # b'ajclbk'
```

If necessary, we can `.decode` that to a string at the end, just as we would `encode` while creating `X`.

Comment: I think it is fair to mention that the "preparation" of the input is relatively expensive.